Building a DIY BGA Rework Machine


simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
I am trying to build a DIY BGA reflow machine. I have a very crude schematic, but the idea is run each of the 6 heating elements in parallel. Doing the math, I have found that the equivalent resistance would be around 4.88 ohms. This would leave the circuit requiring almost 25A. I want to get it below 20A so that I can run it in the house. An idea that comes to mind would be to install a 2 or 3 ohm resistor in parallel to lower the current draw below 20A. I'm not sure if I need a PSU or if I can wire straight into the 120. I also saw some other videos on the subject where they install a circuit breaker as a protection. Any advice or tips on how to build and wire this safely without burning my house down would be greatly appreciated!

The “schematic” you drew is very hard to read. Use the CircuitLab tool built into this site. Edit the question then click on the little schematic button above the edit area. When drawing the schematic; use resistor symbols for the heater, a custom “box” symbol for the SSR, a voltage source for the power supply, and add descriptive text as needed.

what is the purpose of the arrow heads on the lines? ... it makes a cluttered looking diagram

@Kuba hasn't forgotten Monica I have redone my schematic

”install a 2 or 3 ohm resistor in parallel to lower the current draw” That would increase the power consumption, not lower it.

Why are there so many heaters? What voltage is across them? Could you simply use lower power heaters?

I assume that REX-C100 is a digital temperature controller. Would it be better to control the top and bottom heaters separately instead of having two controllers fighting to control one relay?

@AndrewMorton Yes, I could use two separate relays. The top heater and bottom heater need to be controlled separately. I have this many as I am heating some rather large PCBs and this was the best I could do to hit the specific surface area/ They are rated for 110V/500W and the top heater by itself is 110V/450W. Essentially I would like to wire this in a way so that I can preheat PCBs and remove large BGAs without burning my house down or adding in a breaker to my breaker panel. Each side of the PCB needs to reach between 200-250C.

I read reflow in the question body, and rework in the title.

Schematic is a mess since hot seems to be connected to neutral. That aside: If you want to use less power you should use heaters that use less power, or use less heaters.
Do you really need 20 amps of heat? That's 2400 watts. Stand next to the biggest space heater you can buy in the store - imagine all that heat going into your rework machine - do you really need it all, or can you use less?
Notice that if you put a resistor in series (where it needs to be to reduce the power) the resistor becomes another heater. Which leads to another idea: placing two heaters in series instead of parallel. They will each output somewhere between a quarter and a half of the heat (depending on how much the resistance changes with temperature) as they would in parallel. Of course you'll have less heat.
If you are making your own heaters from coils of resistance wire, make the wire longer. Longer = more resistance = less heat. You might think it's the opposite, that a longer heating coil would make more heat, but it doesn't.
